# Context path is not setting in tomcat 5

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, tomcat5.5

One of our project we deployed in tomcat 5.5. our code is not an war file. deployed as a jar.
and we did not deploy directly under webapps . we created new folder and placed everything over there.
and we configured that path in server.xml under context tag

```
<code>
< Context path="/ABC" docBase="/app/apache-tomcat-5.5.26/webapps/ABC/"
                 debug="1" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">

  < /Context>
</code>
```

The problem is.
we were able to land on home page but the images are not load and none of the links are not working 
Home page link ; //ip:port/ABC/home.jsp

when we click any of the links then the context path is getting removed like the below 
one of the link : //ip:port/firstlink.jsp

please help me where we have to config the context path

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you links generated? Are they relative? Or maybe absolute like `<a href="/home.jsp">`. Some sample code could help.

Comment: <ul id="quickLinksMenu" class="menu">
            <li><a href="/home.jsp">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/search/advancedSearch.jsp">Search</a></li>
            <script language="javascript" src="/svg/charts.js"></script>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="hideCurrentMenu(); return openChart();">Charts</a>

Answer (score 0):

Your link `<a href="/home.jsp">` is absolute to your domain, you need to include the context in the URL. To obtain the current context use `request.getContextPath`

> **getContextPath**
>
> String getContextPath()
>
> Returns the portion of the request URI that indicates the context of
>   the request. The context   path always comes first in a request URI.
>   The path starts with a "/" character but does not end with a "/"
>   character. For servlets in the default (root) context, this method
>   returns "".
>
> ...
>
> Returns:
>   a String specifying the portion of the request URI that indicates the context of the request

[HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath())

You can retrieve this value in JSP with `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`. Your link should be:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home.jsp">Home</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. actually i removed the /ABC in the context tag. after that we are able to navigate to all pages its works, 
but the issue is the images and javascripts and css are not loading at all. but every folder we placed under ABC only. when we directly try to access a script or css files like below 
/ip:host/css/menuscrip.css . it throws 404 expextion.
 but we can able to access the pages 
/ip:port/home.jsp 
some differnt page 
/ip:port/search/simpleSearch.jsp 

Why the scripts,images and css are not loading? Please suggest what would be the reason 
Thanks in advance